# RSpec Error - "Invalid Option"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, autotest, spork

I keep getting an issue when running RSpec with Autotest. My 
~/.autotest file looks like this:

```
require 'autotest/growl' 
require 'autotest/fsevent' 
Autotest.add_hook :initialize do |autotest| 
        autotest.add_mapping(/^spec\/requests\/.*_spec\.rb$/) do 
        autotest.files_matching(/^spec\/requests\/.*_spec\.rb$/) 
        end 
end
```

Any thoughts on what's wrong?

```
bundle exec /Users/TTS/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/ruby -S /Users/ 
TTS/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rspec-core-2.3.1/bin/rspec --tty '/ 
Users/TTS/Rails/sample_app/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb' 
'/Users/TTS/Rails/sample_app/spec/controllers/ 
sessions_controller_spec.rb' '/Users/TTS/Rails/sample_app/spec/ 
controllers/users_controller_spec.rb' '/Users/TTS/Rails/sample_app/ 
spec/models/user_spec.rb' '/Users/TTS/Rails/sample_app/spec/requests/ 
layout_links_spec.rb' '/Users/TTS/Rails/sample_app/spec/requests/ 
users_spec.rb' 
/Users/TTS/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/ 
core/option_parser.rb:18:in `parse!': invalid option: --tty 
(OptionParser::InvalidOption) 
        from /Users/TTS/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/ 
rspec/core/option_parser.rb:4:in `parse!' 
        from /Users/TTS/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/ 
rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:64:in `parse_command_line_options' 
        from /Users/TTS/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/ 
rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:46:in `parse_options' 
        from /Users/TTS/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/ 
rspec/core/runner.rb:41:in `run' 
        from /Users/TTS/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/ 
rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, my .autotest file is identical to yours, so that's not the problem.  Can you verify what autotest gem you are running?  (Mine is at 4.4.6 and is working fine.)